# How to associate existing RDS instance to Elastic Beanstalk, with the right storage size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, amazon-rds, elastic-beanstalk

I found the post [How to associate an existing RDS instance to an Elastic Beanstalk environment?](https://serverfault.com/questions/540828/how-to-associate-an-existing-rds-instance-to-an-elastic-beanstalk-environment/540916#540916) and tried to associate my existing RDS instance to Elastic Beanstalk by following it:

- First, creating a manual snapshot from my existing RDS instance, called `existing-rds-to-elasticbeanstalk` (check), notice it's storage size of 20 GB:
  [image: #snapshot:engine=mysql;id=existing-rds-to-elasticbeanstalk]
- Then, going into the EB App Environment Configuration > Database and choosing it (check);
  At this point the values of the lower section are set by default and storage size is set to 5 GB (can not be changed, mysql engine version also wrong):
  [image: #/environment/configuration]
  So I only give it a password, then click [Save] and [Apply].
- I get the following deployment error:

  > Creating RDS database: ... failed Reason: Invalid storage size for
  >   engine name mysql and storage type gp2: 5

  [image: #/environment/events]

The question is how to actually make this process work. [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.db.html?icmpid=docs_elasticbeanstalk_console) doesn't help.

Comment: The reason I'm trying to do this is just to have the `RDS_` environment variables so I don't save database credentials in my code repo, however I think I'm going to go with dotenv locally and add the env vars myself on EB config instead for that environment...

Comment: This stuff is still happening ):